# How can I get user name by user ID?

Tags: linux, centos

In my FTP client I can see files' owner ID (99).

How do I find out which user is the owner of these files?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Shorter getent version (as long as you don't need just the username)

```
$ getent passwd 99
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
```

Works on at least CentOS 5.6 - will take username or uid as key.

Comment: Interestingly enough centos has done something wierd and user 48 is not listed in passwd.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 == 99 { print $1 }'
nobody
```

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to check it (if you have a shell access) is to: cat /etc/passwd | grep 99

Btw UID 99 usually belongs to "nobody" user.

Comment: getent is a better answer because it works even if the userid is coming from NIS.